# Изменение Датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Пожалуйста помогите решить вопрос. Имеем датафрейм-

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'transaction code': '100 100 102 102 102'.split(),
           'fruit': 'fruit_1 fruit_2 fruit_3 fruit_4 fruit_5'.split(),})
```

df1

Который выглядят соответственно так:
df1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача:
Мне нужно чтобы датафрейм выглядел как на фото и был сгруппирован столбцами "Code" и "Fruit"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите пожалуйста как решить проблему нужно чтоб df1 выглядел как на фото.

Answer (score 1):

```
                        0        1        2        3        4
transaction code      100      100      102      102      102
fruit             fruit_1  fruit_2  fruit_3  fruit_4  fruit_5
```

Если нужно, так как вверху.?
То делается это так:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'transaction code': '100 100 102 102 102'.split(),
           'fruit': 'fruit_1 fruit_2 fruit_3 fruit_4 fruit_5'.split(),})


df1 = df1.T

print(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется ввиду, что надо сгруппировать исходный датафрейм таким образом, чтобы в названии колонок был `transaction code`, а под каждым кодом колонка содержащая названия фруктов, соответствующих коду, то:

```
df = df1.pivot(columns='transaction code', values='fruit')
```